# Making Tetris with p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I have some code so far:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500,550);
}
function draw() {
  background(150);
  o();
}
function block(x,y) {
  rectMode(CENTER)
  rect(x,y, cols, rows, 2)
}
function o() {
  fill(255, 255,0)
  block(width/2, rows);
  block(width/2, rows* 2);
  block(width/2 + cols, cols)
  block(width/2 + cols, cols * 2)
}
```

And I'm wondering what to do next. I thought of creating `drop` function and this is what it would look like:

```
function drop() {
rows += rows;
cols += cols;
}
```

Then add this to the `setup` function:
`frameRate(10);`
So it moves slower, but that wouldn't work.
I don't know how to make the block go down without changing the values of `cols` and `rows`. My question is, how can I make the blocks move down, in a function(for instance, a function called `drop`)?

EDIT: The drop function wouldn't have worked because it would change the size, not the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the block to move, it needs to have an `x` and a `y` position.

Currently, you just hardcoded the position.

```
 block(width/2, rows);
```

Instead, you should do something like this

```
let x;
let y = rows;

function setup() {
   createCanvas(500, 500);
   x = width / 2; //you could not set x before now, because the program didn't yet know what the width was
```

Then, replace your `o()` function with this:

```
function o() {
   fill(255, 255,0)
   block(x, y);
   block(x, y + cols);
   block(x + cols, y);
   block(x + cols, y + cols);
}
```

Finally, you can change the x and y position in your `drop()` function (don't forget to actually call it, too)

```
function drop() {
   y += 10;
}
```

Comment: This worked. And I can do this for all the shapes for tetris, like the L and T? And also should I add y by cols: `y += cols`?

Comment: For somereason it won't let me edit so here is ^^^ comment better: This worked. And I can do this for all the shapes for tetris, like the L and T? And also should I add y by cols: `y += cols`? I also need the blocks to drop as in a clicking motion, so should I lower the framerRate?

Comment: Yes, you can do `y += cols`, and yes, you can do this for all blocks. You can change the frame rate and the amount the blocks fall every frame, too.

Comment: Now how would I run random function (O, L, T, .ext), so a random block appears at different times?

Comment: You could use `let blockNumber = floor(random(9));`and then use a [switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Comment: That's a good idea... I can't belive I didn't think of that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are very welcome! If the answer helped you, you can accept it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I would like your post but I don't even have 15 rep.

Comment: I got bored and followed a tutorial, but I had most of the game done, and I added some stuff to the tutorial. it is on my GitHub repository, https://github.com/golden-arches/tetris-evolved.git.